# Modified comments are not shown in inbox

Tags: feature-request, comments, global-inbox, notifications, comment-edits

When commenting, the first edit is signaled to the receivers, that is, the author of the question/answer and one @person. However, the next edit is no longer shown.

**Proposal**: Signal also edits to receivers. This is particularly useful when people ask back, and add further detail into their comment-question later on.

Currently, the only safe way to see all current comments is to reload a page, which most of the time is just a wasteful operation.

Comment: The problem is notifications are denormalized. Once they're generated, they cannot be modified because they're not actually connected to a post ID. It's just a raw message stored in a database, and will always appear as the text that was originally there when the comment was created. Similarly, if a question's title changes, the title does not change in any previous notifications for that post.

Comment: @animuson: What if changing a comment has the same effect as deleting it and writing a new comment?

Comment: Then the user would get notified of 2 comments. The same problem still applies - once the notification has been generated, it can't be modified or deleted. Deleting a comment would not get rid of the old notification. Re-posting a comment would then create *another* notification.

Comment: @animuson: Yes, the user would be notified twice. I cannot see a problem with that.

Comment: I would consider being notified again just for a comment edit rather annoying, especially considering *most* comment edits are extremely minor in nature or edit something that wouldn't even show in the comment preview.

Comment: @animuson: Maybe there is a simple criterion for "simple" changes? Such that simple changes, are not signaled, but complex are? ( I do not get that many comments anyway).

Comment: @animuson: Maybe show that newly edited comment-message as an "edited" message to better distinguish it?

Comment: @animuson maybe i'm being off topic here, but this is the only question having [tag:comment-edit], so I'll ask anyways, is there any history maintained for comment edits, like the Q&As?

Comment: @NatashaDutta It is possible for us to find the history via the logs, but there is rarely ever a need for that. The system only records the number of edits that occur.